# no pg_hba.conf entry for host "x.x.x.x", user "<username>", database "<database_name>", SSL off

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, heroku

I've seen many incarnations of this issue on Stack Overflow and the like over the past few hours, but none of the recommendations seem to be helping me. I am building an app using Node, Express, Heroku, and Postgresql, and when I tried to make my first migration, I ran the following commands:

```
npm run db:create:migration migration_name
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

When I ran this, I got an error that reads:

```
no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<host_ip>", user "<username>", database "<database_name>", SSL off
```

is my computer's ip address,  is my postgres database's username that can be seen from the Heroku console, and  is my postgres database's name which can be seen on that same console, if that info is helpful whatsoever. From what I understand, this means I need to add a line to my pg_hba.conf file, which is located at /usr/local/var/postgres. I tried many different lines based on suggestions and my own understanding of the format used in this configuration file, but alas, that error persisted. This is a shame too because it really seems `host all all all trust` should have worked (even if that is bad practice from a security standpoint). I have also been restarting postgres before trying to migrate again using the following command:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log restart
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure about that config file location? Usually configs are in /etc/ -tree, not in /usr/local -tree. But It depends on your settigns and default settings depends on your distribution.  Line you've been adding to pg_hba.conf would be useful information. And this topic would fit better on ServerFault than in StackOverflow

Comment: Sadly I'm pretty sure that's the config file location. When I run `ps aux | grep postgres` the aforementioned location is listed. Also when I make incorrect changes to that file restarting the server gives an error. I've added a lot of different lines trying to fix this error, but the one I'm most confused about that doesn't work is `host all all all trust`. It seems to me that that line should effectively be a catch-all, but that still gives me an error. Also sorry if SO was a bad place to post this, this is my 2nd question ever asked so still learning the ropes. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: As always, look into the PostgreSQL log file. That will give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

In the line you added to your pg_hba.conf file, the first value should probably be `hostnossl` instead of `host`. Also I would stick to md5 authentication.

Also in the address field try `::/0` instead of `all`.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. `hostnossl` still gives the error. You're definitely right about md5 authentication, I've been thinking of that as the next step. Switching to ::/0 still didn't fix the error - the value shown in the error is ipv4, if that is useful information

Comment: Did you restart postgres service after edits? Also have you specified listening addresses in postresql.conf?

Comment: Yep, I have been restarting the service after every change. And I also specified listening addresses in postgresql.conf